# Disk Usage Script Displays Wrong Output

Tags: bash, scripting

I wrote a simple bash script to check disk usage and to send an email alert for all partitions over 85%. I want the output to look like this:

"/dev/mapper/rootvg-root is at 87%. An email has been sent to your administrator."

However, the current script prints every partition and the percent used doesn't match the right partition. Code below with output:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
admin="foobar@gmail.com"
threshold="85"

util=`df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/.$//'`
part=`df -h | tail -n +2 | head -$1 | awk '{print $1}'`

for i in $util;
do

if [ $i -ge $threshold ]; then

echo "$part is currently at ${i}%. An email has been sent to your             administrator." 
mail -s "Critical Alert: $part is currently at ${i}%. Clear space immeadiately!" $admin

fi
done
```

Output:

```
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root
devtmpfs
tmpfs
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-u01
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-apps
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp is currently at 92%. An email has been sent to your administrator.
```

/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp is not at 92%, /dev/mapper/rootvg-root is and the other partitions below 85% should not be showing.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
admin="foobar@gmail.com"
threshold="85"

df -l --output=source,pcent | while IFS=" %" read -r part i; do
    if [ $i -ge $threshold ] 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "$part is currently at ${i}%. An email has been sent to your             administrator." 
        mail -s "Critical Alert: $part is currently at ${i}%. Clear space immeadiately!" $admin
    fi
done
```